# 'Could not get dependencies for project reference' when include Connector/Net from Mysql

Tags: mysql, .net, visual-studio-2015, .net-assembly, mysql-connector

When complie my solution get the error 'Could not get dependencies for project reference' if include the MySql.Data.dll but the reference and the file are included.

Comment: Did you try many of the suggestions you get when you search for "Could not get dependencies for project reference"? Might be as easy as checking those references and rebuilding.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution.
Is important verify the version supported. I used the version 6.10.6 connector and my project is in 4.5, only changed a the version of framework 4.5.2 and all is fine.

Here the Connector/Net Requirements
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-versions.html